# Does angular-cli's environmentSource file always loaded?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I searched the docs and couldn't find the answer, does angular-cli's 'environmentSource' file is always loaded no matter what environment i choose? (e.g. prod)

I'm setting my project to work with different env files for dev,staging and prod and wanted to know if this file is always loaded so i can put the general env configurations there.

I'l elaborate, lets say my angular-cli file looks like this:

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
"dev": "environments/environment.ts",
"prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

and i run the build with --prod, will both "environment.ts" (which is set as the 'environmentSource') and "environment.prod.ts" will be loaded? what i mean is if i have baseUrl in environment.ts but not in environment.prod.ts will i still be able to use baseUrl when running on --prod?

Thanks,

Raz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the "environments/environment.ts" is used in your code. But when building/serving for a specific environment, the content of that file is replaced dynamically by another environment file if needed.

If you run with the `--prod` flag, then it means thant `environment.prod.ts` will overwrite `environment.ts`. So in your code, you always import `environment.ts`, but with `--prod` the content will actually be the one of `environment.prod.ts`

Comment: it overwrite it entirely or just the variables that are same in the file? what i mean is if i have baseUrl in environment.ts but not in environment.prod.ts will i still be able to use baseUrl when running on --prod?

Comment: I think it's overriden completely, so you would not be able to use that variable. The best way is to try to confirm

Answer (score 2):

environmentSource will replace environments > source.

find-

```
"environments": {
"source": "environments/environment.ts",
"dev": "environments/environment.ts",
"prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

and replace with:

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
"dev": "environments/environment.ts",
"prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

A new environmentSource entry replaces the previous source entry inside environments.

Comment: I've edited my question, i think you didn't fully understood me. i wanted to understand if both environmentSource and the env i chose will be loaded (e.g. prod)